# Get height of image and apply that height to a different div so they match

Tags: jquery, css, height

I have an image that I need to get the height of (because it's different on every page) and apply that same height to a different div on the page.

Here's my code

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(".myimage img").load(function() {
        var imageHeight = $(this).height();
        $('.somebox').css("height",imageHeight);

    });
});
```

Here's a link to my jsfiddle of my attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/mGB5Y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.myimage").each(function() {
        $('.somebox').css("height",$(this).innerHeight());
    });
});
```

Bonus: [The working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGB5Y/1/)

Or, even better:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.somebox').css("height",$("img.myimage").innerHeight());
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you can and you feel that an answer is right, you should accept it by clicking the check mark on its left. Also, welcome to SO, hope you'll stay!

Comment: Hmm...it doesn't seem to be working on my live implementation.  I'm getting height="0" when using it with Drupal.  There are several images on the page (all the same size), does that affect it?  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a link to your live?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in your `js_injector_1.js` - you can't have `<script>` tags in there!

Comment: Thanks, but I disabled that and still no luck.